# Error at Remote Debugging in Eclipse

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, yocto, gdbserver

I am trying to debug an application remotely in Eclipse. When I start debugging, the application is deployed and the gdbserver is started on the target. This seems to work automatically without any mistakes, but then following error occurs:

> 'Launching helloworld Build(GNU)' has encountered a problem.
>
> Could not determine GDB version using command: `/usr/bin/gdb --version`

When I expand  `<<Details` in Eclipse this is shown:

> Could not determine GDB version using command: `/usr/bin/gdb --version`
>
> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
>
> ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

In a console on the target `/usr/bin/gdb --version` is showing me the version and when I open a Python shell I can `import encodings` without errors.

Does anybody know where this error comes from? I wasn't sure about how to tag this question since I have no clue in which area the solution will be.

What I tried so far:

- In Eclipse/Debug Configurations: Commands to execute before application: Several `export` commands to Python.
- Same in `/etc/profile`.
- `bitbake -e python | grep "^PACKAGES="` : Inserted every python package into my image recipe via `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`.
- [...]

Comment: Looks like eclipse is trying to run host gdb, not your target toolchain debugger (probably something like foo-bar-gdb). Is this is path? Can you run it (foo-bar-gdb --version)?

Comment: I tried even with the path of host debugger (Host system is ubuntu and `/usr/bin/gdb --version` is working there like on the target)

Comment: Yes, but eclipse is expected to run target debugger on your host PC and make it connect to gdbserver on your board. It's strange it's trying to run gdb (not leg-something-gdb --version or similar) at all. Can you start target debugger on your PC?

Comment: @dbrank0 How would I do that?

Comment: Just run it. If your toolchain has leg-something- prefix and you have it in your path, run leg-something-gdb --version (host version should be included with toolchain).

Comment: I created the toolchain with `bitbake meta-ide-support`. When I now `source` the enviroment and run `gdb` again the same error as above pops up